# How to open pnp search result links in web part on same page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am creating a KnowledgeBase, in which I had several site pages created. On my home page, I have added a pnp search bar for users to search for "How to..." and below search bar I have added search results web part which currently displays correct results.

Currently when someone clicks on result link, it opens replacing the whole page. However, my team requested to add a web part beside search result in web part which will show the page requested on same page.

For which I created 2 column section with left column showing results and right column shows embed. How can I show dynamically the page requested from search result in that embed web part?

Any help would be really appreciated.